# Botão/link dentro de uma view redirecionando para outra view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho o seguinte endereço de uma `view`:

```
http://localhost/Configuracao/Details/1
```

Onde crie um botão/link que redireciona para outro endereço de outra `view` da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("~/Views/Ativos/Index", Model.Id)" title="Visualizar" class="btn btn-info">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Ativos 
</a>
```

Só que ao clicar o endereço fica:

```
http://localhost/Configuracao/~/Views/Ativos/Index
```

Como efetuar este direcionamento?

Comment: Você já tentou chamar direto a View Index do Controller Ativos?
**href="@Url.Action("index","Ativos", Model.Id)"**

Comment: Você quer passar o parâmetro ID junto com a URL? Ficando **http://localhost/Ativos/Index/1**?

Comment: @Renilson Andrade Ih camarada tudo bem!? Sou o Jothaz tá lembrado? Era isto mesmo! Funcionou. Elabora a resposta para eu marcar como correta. E muito obrigado!

Comment: Faltou o H no nome, mas lembro sim, esse avatar me ajudou bastante. Que bom que pude retribuir de uma pequena forma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode chamar a View Index direto do Controller Ativo:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Ativos", Model.Id)" title="Cancelar" class="btn btn-info">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Ativos 
    </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa usar `@Url.Action`:

```
<a href="/Ativos/Index/@Model.Id" title="Cancelar" class="btn btn-info">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Ativos 
</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado é sempre bom ter várias visões de como solucionar um problema.